# iPhone App Upload - CodeSign Missing?

Tags: iphone, upload, codesign

For a long time now I have been searching through the forum whilst teaching myself the delights of iPhone programming, and I thank you all for the massive number of questions you have unknowingly helped me with!

I seem to have come up against a brick wall regarding the upload of my finished application to Apple and would appreciate any help/advice that you may be willing to give.

This is my first upload to apple so apologies if this is all a little sketchy!

After some tweaking I have successfully managed to follow Apples guidelines on creating a new Distribution profile for my project, applied my new Distribution certificates in the Target info and got the project to successfully build. Sounds good! Problem is when I upload this to apple i get their generic "App is not Signed" error.

After one hell of a late night and some research I realised that in the detailed Build Log of my application there is no line that includes the word "CodeSign" as apple suggest. It appears that XCode when compiling isn’t even attempting to CodeSign .app.

What I have tried:
Creating new AppIDs, Certificates and Distriution profiles (a number of times).
Trying to package an Apple example (untampered).
After a 7.5 hour download i have reinstalled XCode to no avail.

Is there something simple I am missing? Has anyone else experienced this where XCode doesn’t add a CodeSign row to the Detailed build log?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Regards,

Ralph

---

Solved

I think the fact I wasn’t building under device played quite a big part in this. After much (more) tweaking I managed to get it to CodeSign by:
Re-installing XCode
Running the Clean All targets function a huge number of times in-between everything I did.
Deleted all certs on my Keychain and downloaded all new ones.
Making sure I was using device and my Distribution profile on both Target and Project settings.
And a lot of sweat and tears..!

Thanks for your help!

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's weird. You're definitely building for the device and not the simulator?

Double check your Code Signing Identity in your Release/Appstore configuration settings.
It should be Any iPhone Device: iPhone Distribution: Your company name

Comment: Thanks for your reply! As above, it seems to have done the trick. Its always the simle things that trip me up! Cheers